# Parameter count mismatch exception when using BeginInvoke

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I have a backgroundworker in a C++ .NET forms application which runs async. In the DoWork function of this backgroundworker I want to add rows to a datagridview, however I can't really figure out how to do this with BeginInvoke as the code I have doesn't seem to work.

The code I have

```
delegate void invokeDelegate(array<String^>^row);

....
In the DoWork of the backgroundworker
....

array<String^>^row = gcnew array<String^>{"Test", "Test", "Test"};
if(ovlgrid->InvokeRequired)
    ovlgrid->BeginInvoke(gcnew invokeDelegate( this, &Form1::AddRow), row);

....

void AddRow(array<String^>^row)
{
 ovlgrid->Rows->Add( row );
}
```

The error I get is:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.

When I change to code to not pass any parameters it just works, the code than becomes:

```
delegate void invokeDelegate();

...
In the DoWork function
...

if(ovlgrid->InvokeRequired)
     ovlgrid->BeginInvoke(gcnew invokeDelegate( this, &Form1::AddRow));

...
void AddRow()
{
     array<String^>^row = gcnew array<String^>{"test","test2","test3"};
     ovlgrid->Rows->Add( row );
}
```

The problem though is that I want to pass parameters.
I was wondering what I'm doing wrong which causes the parametercountexception and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you've run into is [`BeginInvoke` takes an *array* of parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824.aspx) and you pass it an array which happens to be the one parameter.

> **Parameters**
>
> *method*
>
> Type: `System.Delegate`
>
> The delegate to a method that takes parameters specified in `args`, which is pushed onto the Dispatcher event queue.
>
> *args*
>
> Type: `System.Object[]`
>
> An array of objects to pass as arguments to the given method. Can be `null`.

Therefore, `BeginInvoke` takes this to mean you have **3** string parameters to the method: `"test"`, `"test2"`, and `"test3"`. You need to pass an array containing just your `row`:

```
array<Object^>^ parms = gcnew array<Object^> { row };
ovlgrid.BeginInvoke(gcnew invokeDelegate(this, &Form1::AddRow), parms);
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for my problem. I was thinking that the '... array<Object^>^ args' was some kind of variable argument list instead of an array of parameters cause of the three dots before it, but I now see what did go wrong at my code.